# CSS3 Crossbrowser Gradient Background with rgb/rgba and fallbacks

Tags: css, gradient, rgb, rgba

I want to try and get a cross browser gradient effect working with `rgb` values with fall backs in case the browser doesn't support it.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/hUxdh/

I believe I've covered the majority of browsers, but I have a few questions:

1. Are there any other browsers that I have missed which are commonly used, as well as what properties would be needed for devices such as iPads/SmartPhones, or would they render from one of the currently used properties?
2. If by chance the gradient isn't rendered, is having the original `background: rgb(50, 50, 50);` enough to generate just a solid colour?
3. With the `filter` value, I couldn't get it working by using `rgb` values and had to resort to using a `hex` value instead, not that this is a huge problem, but I'm trying to only use `rgb` values. Is there a way round this or does it just not accept them?
4. If I was to use `rgba` instead of `rgb` would I then need to have a `rgba` gradient background value, an `rgb` gradient background value as a fall back for not rendering the alpha transparency and then a solid background fall back in case no gradient was rendered at all? Or would the browser ignore the alpha transparency value and just display the `rgb` from the `rgba` without a separate `rgb` background fall back?
5. As a final fall back for everything, would having a set `hex` value at the start of the CSS properties be needed? I guess there is no harm is adding a `hex` value but the idea of using `rgb` is if `rgba` is usable it makes for a quick and easy colour change throughout the site. So having a fall back `hex` value would make using `rgb/rgba` pointless for what I'm intending it's used for since I'd need to go through and edit all `hex` values anyway.

I've done a bit of searching and examples vary, understanding is misinterpreted between different people and I was just try to create an accurate working example of getting the desired outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May i suggest you this website to help you with your Gradients and fallback:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: That is definitely an amazing generator, thank you very much Simon! A couple questions still stand though such as if a browser doesn't read `rgba` does it just read the `rgb` value and ignore the alpha transparency? Also is a `hex` value ever needed as an ultimate fall back?

Comment: @JoeMottershaw My love for Colorzilla's Ultimate gradient editor cant be measured so (+1), but as the case might be that you want to use other things like rounded corner and shadow I'm just gonna throw in http://www.css3pie.com - Note that the website itself is a demo of how the shadows and rounded corners work in it.